# using useRef instead of a setState state variable in a React component when registering eventListeners with a handler that refers to that variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  const movingRef = useRef(false);

  const handleStartMove = (e) => {
    movingRef.current = true;

    e.stopPropagation();
    // handleMove doesn't take the latest value if we use a state instead of a ref
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMove);
    if (onMoveStart) {
      onMoveStart(e, movingRef.current, angle);
    }

  };

  const handleMove = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!movingRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    this.moveDOMElement(e);
  };
```

I have something like this and I noticed if I replaced movingRef = useRef(false) with const [moving, setMoving] = useState(false), it doesn't work. It works with refs and I read that useRef changes propagate faster since the callback function "handleMove" takes the cached value of the setState variable moving (or state), instead of taking the latest value, but if you use ref you will always use the latest value. Is this the case?

I heard that this is a closure-related behavior and using a state variable causes synchronization and side effect issues while using refs allows us to avoid that and get what we would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `useRef` when the value has *does not* need the component to re-render. The `.current` value of a ref is a variable that you control, updating it *does not* tell React to re-render.
- `useState` is for values that *should* queue a re-render. When you call the `setX` returned by `useState`, React queues a re-render and the value will be the updated one on the next render. This is mentioned in [`useState`'s caveats](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-caveats):

> The `set` function only updates the state variable for the *next* render. If you read the state variable after calling the set function, you will still get the old value that was on the screen before your call.

From the limited code you posted it looks like `movingRef` is not referenced in the template, updating it does not need a re-render, and so `useRef` is a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, when you are using `useState` the set state is asynchronous. So it will not update the state immediately.
`useRef` gives you a mutable object. the `movingRef` gives you the most recent value and can be updated directly.
In your context, the `useState` may not update quickly for the `mousemove` event, so it's better to use `useRef` since it's mutable and not tied to the component's render cycle.